# Covariance Functions of Stationary Gaussian Random Processes

Tags: self-study, covariance, independence, gaussian-process, white-noise

I am trying to solve this question:

Suppose that $n(t)$, $−∞ < t < ∞$ is a stationary Gaussian random process with covariance function $E\{n(t)n(t-\tau)\} = \delta(\tau) + {5 \over 4}e^{-\left|\tau \right|} = K_n(\tau)$

Assume that $n(t) = n_c(t) + w(t)$, where $w(t)$ and $n_c(t)$ are independent stationary Gaussian random processes, $w(t)$ is white Gaussian noise, and $n_c(t)$ has mean finite energy over any finite interval.

Find the covariance functions for $w(t)$ and $n_c(t)$.

Denote the covariance function for $n_c(t)$ by $K_c(\tau)$.

My approach is that i substituted $n(t) = n_c(t) + w(t)$ in $E\{n(t)n(t-\tau)\} = \delta(\tau) + {5 \over 4}e^{-\left|\tau \right|} = K_n(\tau)$ and get the following:

$E\{n(t)n(t-\tau)\} = E\{n_c(t)n_c(t-\tau)\} + E\{n_c(t)w(t-\tau)\} + E\{w(t)n_c(t-\tau)\} + E\{w(t)w(t-\tau)\}$

How can i proceed from here?

Thanks...

Comment: The last expression is wrong, where did you find the squares? Do the calculations again, substituting for both $n(t)$ and for $n(t-\tau)$. . Also: if $w(t)$ is white noise, we know what its autocovariance function is already.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos $n(t) = n_c(t) + w(t)$ so i am substituting this in the covariance equation. Since the processes are stationary i can say that $n_c(t - \tau) = n_c(t)$ and $w(t - \tau) = w(t)$ or am i mistaken?

Comment: Totally mistaken. Stationarity refers to certain equalities across the index related to the distributions of the variables, not the variables themselves. Under what you wrote in your comment, you would have a constant process.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos then it must be this: $E\{n(t)n(t-\tau)\} = E\{n_c(t)n_c(t-\tau)\} + E\{n_c(t)w(t-\tau)\} + E\{w(t)n_c(t-\tau)\} + E\{w(t)w(t-\tau)\}$ what should i do next?